# Homeomorphism between Convex sets - writing a proof

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Consider $\Omega$ a nonempty open, convex and bounded polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$. 
What's the easiest way to prove it is homeomorphic to the open unit ball? 
How to explicitly define an homeomorphism?
I've tried considering the following situation. WLOG, I can assume $\Omega$ to be compactly contained within the ball, and $0 \in \Omega$. Indeed, I can always translate and shrink $\Omega$ to get to this starting point. It is clear, now, that for every $x \in \Omega$, I can take the supremum over $ r \in [0,1]$ such that $\frac{rx}{|x|} \in \Omega$; this supremum will always be $ <1$. Now the next step is much more difficult. 
Do you think this is the best strategy? Do you suggest something else?

Comment: How elementary do you want this proof to be? By the classification of surfaces, the boundary of a polytope is a topological sphere; the homeomorphism certifying this extends to a homeomorphism between the polytope and the ball.

Comment: I need to show the existence of a 1-1 and onto continuous function with continuous inverse. Is it possible to get a proof using the strategy with that supremum? I don't have to get too much topological, though.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Your $r$ tells you the distance of the boundary (in the direction of $x$) from $0$. All points in this direction are a certain fraction of that distance from $0$, and are sent to points in the ball with norm that fraction pointing in the same direction as the argument. I leave it to you to prove that this is a homeomorphism.